# PL/SQL: USING clause and dynamic variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following stored procedure is meant to take in a parameter `my_seconds`, create a date variable `my_date` which is the current date plus (or minus) the number in `my_seconds`, and print the date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test (my_seconds NUMBER)
IS    
my_date DATE;
BEGIN    
   execute immediate 'select sysdate + interval '':1'' second from dual' into my_date USING &my_seconds;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE:' || my_date);  
END
```

But what happens is that when compiling the procedure (using Oracle SQL developer), it prompts for the value of my_seconds, and the procedure is not created correctly.

How should this line:

```
execute immediate 'select sysdate + interval '':1'' second from dual' into my_date USING &my_seconds ;
```

be re-written?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the ampersand `&` from `my_seconds`.

Comment: Once you get your code to compile you'll encounter an error when trying to execute your dynamic SQL.  `interval ':1' second` is an [interval string literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221).  As such you can't put a variable inside the quotation marks, it needs to be a constant value. instead you'll need to use either the `NUMTODSINTERVAL` or `NUMTOYMINTERVAL` function to convert a numeric value to an interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your procedure like this, without execute immediate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test (my_seconds NUMBER)
IS    
my_date DATE;
BEGIN    
   select sysdate + my_seconds * interval '1' second into my_date from dual;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE:' || my_date);  
END
```

Comment: Even shorter: `my_date := sysdate + my_seconds * interval '1' second;`

Comment: Even shorter: `my_date constant date := sysdate + my_seconds * interval '1' second;`

Answer (score 2):

You can forgo the SQL statement all together and use this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test( my_seconds NUMBER )
IS
  my_date DATE;
BEGIN
  my_date := sysdate + numtodsinterval( my_seconds, 'second' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'DATE:' || my_date );
END;
```

Doing so will avoid switching contexts from PL/SQL to SQL and back again.

However, to answer your original question of how to compile the code in SQL Developer and avoid the prompts for bind variables caused by the colons in your code, use the Run Script command instead of the Run Statement command (F5 instead of F9 with default key mappings or click the icon that looks like a page with a green triangle instead of the icon of just a green triangle).

Alternatively right click the Procedures node in the connections tree, choose New Procedure, fill out the blanks as appropriate, and click OK, then paste your code into the procedure editor that was opened.  From here you can click the two gears icon or type CTRL-S to compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too. It works

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_AV_PROC (my_seconds NUMBER)
IS    
my_date TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN    
   execute immediate 'select :1 + INTERVAL''' ||my_seconds||''''||'SECOND'|| ' from dual ' into my_date USING SYSTIMESTAMP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE:' || my_date);  
END;
```